# How to style CheckBox to remove border

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a `CheckBox` control in one of my windows that's just there to display whether something is true/false - I don't want my users interacting with it.

By default, setting `IsEnabled="False"` grays out the box, which is fine. However, I thought it would be neater and more obvious if I kept a solid check mark and removed the border.

At first I set `BorderThickness="0"`, which seemed to do nothing. So I went to the style instead, and put this in my resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderlessCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Border Background="#FFAEB3B9" BorderThickness="0" />
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                </BulletDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This removes the textbox completely - as best I can tell what I'm inadvertently doing overriding the entire style and, since I'm not specifying the check as part of my style, no check is appearing.

Is there a straightforward way of removing the border from a textbox without re-styling the entire control from scratch?

EDIT: I did try BorderThickness:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the border from the `CheckBox` by setting the `BorderThickness` property.

```
<CheckBox Content="Test" BorderThickness="0" />
```

---

If you want to edit a control template, the easiest way is to open your solution in Blend, right click the control and edit the template.

[image: Edit template]

Drill down the control tree and you'll find the checkBoxBorder control which you want to hide. Here you see that the `BorderThickness` comes from a `TemplateBinding` (thus from the property on the `CheckBox` itself):

```
<Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
    <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
        <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know you could create template copies so easily. Just to demonstrate that I'm not a lazy ass, I have added a screenshot showing that I tried the BorderThickness and it didn't do anything. I'm using the Metro style - I presume this must override control of that property for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself and found out the following thanks to Bart's response above. I edited a copy of the template for MahApps Metro Checkbox and below is the variable used. Doing the following will remove the rectangle around the checkbox.

In Style

```
<Setter Property="mah:CheckBoxHelper.CheckStrokeThickness" Value="0" />
```

or directly in checkbox xaml

```
mah:CheckBoxHelper.CheckStrokeThickness="0"
```